# Convert array index in a custom string layout?

Tags: php

I have an array called `$context` with this structure:

```
array(2) {
[0]=>
 array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(6) "Foo"
  ["username"]=>
  string(6) "Test"
}
[1]=>
array(2) {
["name"]=>
string(4) "John"
["username"]=>
string(3) "Doe"
 }
}
```

I want convert it into this string:

string 1:

```
0: array(
   'name' => 'Foo',
   'username' => 'Test',
)
```

string 2:

```
1: array(
   'name' => 'John',
   'username' => 'Doe',
)
```

How you can see I want save the current index in the iteration and display the array content formatted as `'name'` and `'username'` in a single line. I already tried with this code:

```
    $export = '';

    foreach($context as $key => $value)
    {
        $export .= "{$key}: ";
        print_r($value);
        $export .= preg_replace(array(
            '/=>\s+([a-zA-Z])/im',
            '/array\(\s+\)/im',
            '/^  |\G  /m'
        ), array(
            '=> $1',
            'array()',
            '    '
        ), str_replace('array (', 'array(', var_export($value, true)));

        print_r($export);

        $export .= PHP_EOL;
    }

    return str_replace(array('\\\\', '\\\''), array('\\', '\''), rtrim($export));
```

but I'm looking for a more optimized solution, any suggest?

Comment: Your sub-arrays are strictly how in yr example? they all have 2 elements, each with 'name' and 'username' as keys?

Comment: @fusion3k, yes have only two elements in this example, but in future I can add more Keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my code:

```
$context = [['name'=>'Foo','username'=>'Test'],['name'=>'John','username'=>'Doe']];
$schema = "   '%s' => '%s'";
$lineBreak = PHP_EOL;

foreach( $context as $idx => $array )
{
    $lines = array();
    foreach( $array as $key => $val )
    {
        $lines[] = sprintf( $schema, $key, $val );
    }
    $output = "{$idx}: array({$lineBreak}".implode( ",{$lineBreak}", $lines )."{$lineBreak})";
    echo $output.$lineBreak;
}
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/FCdid)**</kbd>

**It will works independently from the number of elements in sub-arrays**

I have used classic built-in function `sprintf` to format each array row: [see more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

You can change `$lineBreak` with you preferred endLine character;
In the above example, each string is printed, but (you have a `return` in your function, so i think inside a function), you can modify in this way:

```
$output = array();
foreach( $context as $idx => $array )
{
    (...)
    $output[] = "{$idx}: array({$lineBreak}".implode( ",{$lineBreak}", $lines )."{$lineBreak})";
}
```

to have an array filled with formatted string.

You can easly transform it in a function:

```
function contextToString( $context, $schema=Null, $lineBreak=PHP_EOL )
{
    if( !$schema ) $schema = "   '%s' => '%s'";
    $output = array();

    foreach( $context as $idx => $array )
    {
        $lines = array();
        foreach( $array as $key => $val )
        {
            $lines[] = sprintf( $schema, $key, $val );
        }
        $output[] = "{$idx}: array({$lineBreak}".implode( ",{$lineBreak}", $lines )."{$lineBreak})";
    }

    return implode( $lineBreak, $output );
}
```

to change each time the schema and the line break.

**PS:** I see that in you code there is a comma also at the end of the last element of eache array; thinking it was a typo, I have omitted it

---

Edit: I have forgot the comma, added-it.
Edit 2: Added complete function example.
Edit 3: Added link to `sprintf` PHP page

Comment: I edited your code like this: http://pastebin.com/DGBGDunj how you can see the result also return array at the first position how I can fix this? thanks

Comment: also if I insert `$output[] =` I get only `array` with no content returned. You need also to fix the array declaration is `$output = array()` instead of `$output = array[]`;

Comment: @SevengamesXoom Added working function example. Your pastebin doesn't work because you declare `output` as array and then you treat it as string. Yes, fixed array declaration, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, just a question what does `%s` means in the schema?

Comment: is a placeholder for string in `sprintf` function to basic formatting string: [see more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this with personnal toString

```
$a = array(array("name"=>"Foo", "username"=>"Test"), array("name"=>"John", "username"=>"Doe"));

function toString($array){
    $s = ""; $i=0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $s.= $key."=>".$value;
        if($i < count($array)-1)
            $s.=",";
        $i++;
    }
    return $s;
}
$result = array();
$index = 0;

foreach ($a as $value) {
    array_push($result, $index. " : array(" . toString($value).")");
    $index ++;
}

var_dump($result);
```

And the result :

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '0 : array(name=>Foo,username=>Test)' (length=35)
  1 => string '1 : array(name=>John,username=>Doe)' (length=35)
```

The result is in an array but you can change and make what you want

But you can also use json_encode :

```
$result = array();
$index = 0;

foreach ($a as $value) {
    array_push($result, $index. " : array(" . json_encode($value).")");
    $index ++;
}

var_dump($result);
```

With this result :

```
array (size=2)
 0 => string '0 : array({"name":"Foo","username":"Test"})' (length=43)
 1 => string '1 : array({"name":"John","username":"Doe"})' (length=43)
```

Comment: I need only one function for do this

Answer (score 0):

Simplified solution with `strrpos`,`substr_replace` and `var_export`:

```
$arr = [
    array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'username' => 'Doe'
    ),
    array(
    'name' => 'Mike',
    'username' => 'Tyson'
    )
];

/*****************/
$strings = [];
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    $dump = var_export($v, true);
    $last_comma_pos = strrpos($dump,",");
    $cleared_value = substr_replace($dump, "", $last_comma_pos, 1);
    $strings[] = $k.": ".$cleared_value;
}
/*****************/

// Now $strings variable contains all the needed strings
echo "<pre>";
foreach($strings as $str){
    echo $str . "\n";
}

// the output:
0: array (
  'name' => 'John',
  'username' => 'Doe'
)
1: array (
  'name' => 'Mike',
  'username' => 'Tyson'
)
```